# Does Windows linker resolve undefined symbols in DLL with LoadLibrary?

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll, linker

In Linux when I load shared library using `dlopen()` from executable (or shared library) I expect that undefined symbols in this library will be automatically resolved, of course as long as executable (or shared library) defines these symbols.

For example, I have library **A** with these header and source files:

```c
#pragma once
int funcA();
```

```c
#include "A/header.h"
int funcA() {}
```

also I have library **B** with this source file:

```c
#include "A/header.h"
void funcB() {
    funcA();
}
```

for library **B** I specify path to header of library **A**, but I don't link library **A** to library **B**.

In this case, if I load library **B** from library **A** by calling `dlopen()`, then undefined symbol `funcA` in library **B** will be resolved, so library **B** will be able to call `funcA`.

Is it also true for Windows, or I have to manually find addresses for all symbols I need?

Answer (score 0):

After researching already answered questions on Stack Overflow:

- [External symbol resolving in a dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544041/external-symbol-resolving-in-a-dll)
- [Compile to .dll with some undefined references with MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39759060/compile-to-dll-with-some-undefined-references-with-mingw)

I realized that if I want to make something similar work on Windows, I have to create some *import library* for my shared library **A**.

At first I thought it's needed only for MSVC, but looks like MinGW needs import library too, because it's how things work on Windows. Correct me if I miss something.

For me it's big no-no, so probably I will change a way how I work with shared libraries to explicitly retrieve every symbol I need via additional interface. Fortunately, there are not so many of them.